Error interacting with the button in the discord bot
Bot throws this interaction error:

Error interacting with the button in the discord bot

I've done everything in my power, but nothing helps.
Button click handler "Send report"
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: discord.Interaction):
# Check if the click occurred on the "Send report" button
if interaction.component.custom_id == "send_report":
# Send the user instructions on how to submit a report
await interaction.user.send("Please mention the username using @, attach files, and write the reason for the complaint.")
# Send the user confirmation that their report has been submitted
await interaction.response.send_message("Thank you, your report has been submitted!")

Command for submitting a report
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx):
# Send a message with the "Send report" button
embed = discord.Embed(title="Write a complaint about someone here", color=discord.Color.red())
view = discord.ui.View()
view.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="Send report", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="send_report"))
await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

Event handler for attaching a file to a message
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
# Check if the message contains attachments and is sent in a private message to the bot
if message.attachments and message.author.id == admin_id:
# Send administration (in this case, you) information about the complaint
admin_user = await bot.fetch_user(admin_id)
if admin_user:
await admin_user.send("New complaint received:")
await admin_user.send(message.content)
for attachment in message.attachments:
await admin_user.send(attachment.url)
else:
print("Administrator not found.")
await bot.process_commands(message)

Tried everything I could, nothing helped

Please fix the indentation.
